# Graphical intersection of lines in C

Tags: c, intersection, bgi

I have a homework.

**The homework is:** There are 3 lines, theirs end with squares.  *Firstly* The program has to view a circle is the lines are cut each other. (In other way: Take the intersection of the 3 lines). *Secondly*, the program has to change the background, along the lines. Each line's both side define the background with a colour. And how rotating the lines, together with them, the background colour changing. 
There are 3 lines, and 6 background colour. The border of background color is along the lines.

The **programming enviroment** is the DevC++ (we must use the c++ console applicaton, but in the lesson we not coding in c++, just c...)

[Youtube video about the exercise/homework](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cE61F0EsLik&feature=related)

I've tried implement of the lines' intersection, but It doesn't work very well.
And I don't have any idea, *how can I implement of the  colourful background change.*

*What kind of knowledge is needed for it?*

I would like to if somebody can suggest to me some: algorithm, webpage, tutorial, sourecode, anything what can help me. Or what is the name of my homework in english ( to google search)
Cause I don't think, my solution is the best way to prepare my homework (maybe it won't succes)

Here the code, that I have did up to now (but it not perfect. The intersection of lines is not perfectly. It's not a beautiful solution, sorry I am not an expert C programmer):

[sourcode in english](http://codeviewer.org/view/code:1f39)

- PONT = point, dot
- PONTH = aggregation of points
- atir = rewrite
- metszilleszt = fitting of intersection
- szakasz = section, phase...    (there is too many in english-hungarian) or platoon :-D
- eger = mouse
- egérkezelés = mouse control
- balgomb = left button of mouse

  ```
  # include "graphics.h"
  # include <conio.h>
  #include <stdio.h>
  typedef struct {
          float x1,x2,x3;
  } PONTH;

  typedef struct {
          double x,y;
  }PONT;

  PONTH atir(PONT A){
        PONTH C;
        C.x1=A.x;
        C.x2=A.y;
        C.x3=1;
  return C;
  }

  PONTH metszilleszt(PONTH A,PONTH B){
        PONTH C;
        C.x1=(A.x2*B.x3)-(A.x3*B.x2);
        C.x2=-(A.x1*B.x3)+(A.x3*B.x1);
        C.x3=(A.x1*B.x2)-(A.x2*B.x1);
     return C;
  }
  int main()
  {
  //PONT szakasz[4]={100,50,300,200,30,130,140,170};
  PONT szakasz[6]={100,50,300,200,30,130,140,170,30,70,210,40};

  int ap;
  int gd,gm;
  int page =0;
  gd=VGA;gm=VGAMED;
  initgraph(&gd,&gm,"");
  PONTH A,B,C,D,E,F;
  PONTH tmp1,tmp2,tmp3,tmp4,tmp5,tmp6;
  PONT pont;

  for(;;){
   setactivepage(page);
   cleardevice();

   A=atir(szakasz[0]);
   B=atir(szakasz[1]);
   C=atir(szakasz[2]);
   D=atir(szakasz[3]);
   E=atir(szakasz[4]);
   F=atir(szakasz[5]);

   tmp1=metszilleszt(A,B);
   tmp2=metszilleszt(C,D);
   tmp3=metszilleszt(E,F);

   tmp4=metszilleszt(tmp2,tmp1);

   tmp5=metszilleszt(tmp3,tmp1);

   tmp6=metszilleszt(tmp3,tmp2);

   pont.x=int (tmp3.x1/tmp3.x3);
   pont.y=int (tmp3.x2/tmp3.x3);
   //printf("%f %f\n",pont.x,pont.y);


  // good
   if((((tmp4.x2/tmp4.x3)>=szakasz[0].y) && ((tmp4.x2/tmp4.x3)<=szakasz[1].y)) &&
     (((tmp4.x1/tmp4.x3)>=szakasz[0].x) && ((tmp4.x1/tmp4.x3)<=szakasz[1].x)) ||
     (((tmp4.x2/tmp4.x3)>=szakasz[0].y) && ((tmp4.x2/tmp4.x3)<=szakasz[1].y)) &&
     (((tmp4.x1/tmp4.x3)<=szakasz[0].x) && ((tmp4.x1/tmp4.x3)>=szakasz[1].x)))
     {
      setcolor(RED);
      fillellipse(int (tmp4.x1/tmp4.x3),int (tmp4.x2/tmp4.x3),5,5); 
     }

      if((((tmp5.x2/tmp5.x3)>=szakasz[0].y) && ((tmp5.x2/tmp5.x3)<=szakasz[1].y)) &&
     (((tmp5.x1/tmp5.x3)>=szakasz[0].x) && ((tmp5.x1/tmp5.x3)<=szakasz[1].x)) ||
     (((tmp5.x2/tmp5.x3)>=szakasz[0].y) && ((tmp5.x2/tmp5.x3)<=szakasz[1].y)) &&
     (((tmp5.x1/tmp5.x3)<=szakasz[0].x) && ((tmp5.x1/tmp5.x3)>=szakasz[1].x)))
     {
      setcolor(RED);
      //fillellipse(int (tmp5.x1/tmp5.x3),int (tmp5.x2/tmp5.x3),5,5); 
      fillellipse(int (tmp5.x1/tmp5.x3),int (tmp5.x2/tmp5.x3),5,5); 
     }

      if((((tmp6.x2/tmp6.x3)>=szakasz[0].y) && ((tmp6.x2/tmp6.x3)<=szakasz[1].y)) &&
     (((tmp6.x1/tmp6.x3)>=szakasz[0].x) && ((tmp6.x1/tmp6.x3)<=szakasz[1].x)) ||
     (((tmp6.x2/tmp6.x3)>=szakasz[0].y) && ((tmp6.x2/tmp6.x3)<=szakasz[1].y)) &&
     (((tmp6.x1/tmp6.x3)<=szakasz[0].x) && ((tmp6.x1/tmp6.x3)>=szakasz[1].x)))
     {
      setcolor(RED);
      fillellipse(int (tmp6.x1/tmp6.x3),int (tmp6.x2/tmp6.x3),5,5); 
     }

     //else{ setcolor(RED);
    // fillellipse(int (tmp3.x1/tmp3.x3),int (tmp3.x2/tmp3.x3),5,5); }

   /* Egerkezeles */
    if (!balgomb) ap = getactivepoint((pont2d*)szakasz,6,6);
     if (ap >= 0 && balgomb)
     {
      szakasz[ap].x = egerx;
      szakasz[ap].y = egery;
     }
   /* Egerkezeles vege */
   setcolor(WHITE);
    line((int)szakasz[0].x,(int)szakasz[0].y,(int)szakasz[1].x,(int)szakasz[1].y);
    rectangle((int)szakasz[0].x,(int)szakasz[0].y, (int)szakasz[0].x+4, (int)szakasz[0].y+4);
    rectangle((int)szakasz[1].x,(int)szakasz[1].y, (int)szakasz[1].x+4, (int)szakasz[1].y+4);
    line((int)szakasz[2].x,(int)szakasz[2].y,(int)szakasz[3].x,(int)szakasz[3].y);
    rectangle((int)szakasz[2].x,(int)szakasz[2].y, (int)szakasz[2].x+4, (int)szakasz[2].y+4);
    rectangle((int)szakasz[3].x,(int)szakasz[3].y, (int)szakasz[3].x+4, (int)szakasz[3].y+4);
    line((int)szakasz[4].x,(int)szakasz[4].y,(int)szakasz[5].x,(int)szakasz[5].y);
    rectangle((int)szakasz[4].x,(int)szakasz[4].y, (int)szakasz[4].x+4, (int)szakasz[4].y+4);
    rectangle((int)szakasz[5].x,(int)szakasz[5].y, (int)szakasz[5].x+4, (int)szakasz[5].y+4);

   setvisualpage(page);
   page = 1-page;
   if (kbhit()) break;
  }
   getch();
   closegraph();
   return(0);
  }
  ```

Comment: huh the code very much looks like it has been generated from Maple/Matlab or similar. No one would ever write so many casts and so little whitespace/interpunction?

Comment: English names are much more understandable.

Comment: @Griwes: +1, but arguably not universally true :)

Comment: Well, more people speak English than... let me guess... Hungarian? ;)

Comment: Yes Hungarian :-D, I will write their means

Comment: Rather than expecting us to watch a Youtube video (I, for one, am not going to watch it), perhaps you could summarize your homework so that the question is self-sufficient? In addition, please mention your programming environment - the `conio.h` header is *not* standard C.

Comment: Can this not be done algebraically?  That is, is your program expected to analyze an image (or bitmap) and find the intersection of three lines in the image?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the intersections of lines, you should read the article of Loren Shure and Lucio Cetto from Matworks on Loren's blog:

- [Part 1](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2011/08/29/intersecting-lines/)
- [Part 2](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2011/09/08/intersecting-lines-part-2/)

It's in Matlab but the principles are the same.